# ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется кусочек кода.

```
from math import *
print("Введите исходные данные")
print("x0 = ", end='')
x0 = float(input())
print("xs = ", end='')
xs = float(input())
print("x2 = ", end='')
x2 = float(input())
print("a = ", end='')
a = float(input())
print("b = ", end='')
b = float(input())
print("c = ", end='')
c = float(input())
print("Вы ввели:")
print("x0 = %.1f  xs = %.1f  x2 = %.1f" % (x0, xs, x2))
x = x0
y = exp(a) - ((sin(3*x) - log(b, c))/sqrt(1-sqrt(fabs(c-b))**(1/3)))
while x <= x2 + xs / 2:
    Y = exp(a) - ((sin(3*x) - log(b, c))/sqrt(1-sqrt(fabs(c-b))**(1/3)))
    print("x = ", x, "y = ", y)
    x += xs
```

При запуске этого самого кода появляется ошибка

> TypeError: must be real number, not list

Объясните пожалуйста,из-за чего она возникает.

UPD. Ошибка исправлена. Появилась новая:

> ValueError: math domain error

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106895/discussion-on-question-by---valueerror-math-domain-error).

Comment: В общем.Вопрос решен.Всем спасибо за помощь :)